# Avoid running into list out of index error Python

Tags: python, list

How can I compare two `adjacent` elements in an array without running into index out of range error.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def count(n):
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] == n[i+1]:
            counter += 1
    print(counter, n[i])
```

I can see that the problem is when it access the last element in n it can no longer find index i+1 and that's why it generates this error.
but I need to know how to avoid this error while still checking the last element in the array or string( without changing the range to the length of n minus 1.

Comment: "without changing the range to the length of n minus 1" Why that restriction? That seems like exactly what you need.

Comment: By that, I mean that I still want to check the last element and not totally ignore it. but it doesn't have to be using the same for loop.

Comment: `n[i] == n[i+1]:` - if you are at n == len(list)-1   this will try to access outside the list. change the loop to go only up to `for i in range(len(n)-1):` to fix.

Comment: @Ruf when you use `range(len(n) - 1)` the last element is accessed with `n[i+1]`, thus you basically iterate through the whole range of elements.

Comment: Check the last element against what? You simply have to avoid using `n[i+1]` if `i == len(n) - 1`.

Comment: but the last element is not being printed now and that's the problem. I am using print here for simplification but I plan to do a more complicated thing to elements other than printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could this simple `zip` to compare those two adjacent numbers at the same time, and not worrying about index out of bound:

```
def count_adjacent(nums):
    count = 0
    for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
        if a == b: count += 1
    return count

>>> 
>>> count_adjacent([1,1,1,2,2,3, 4, 4, 5])
                      ^ ^   ^       ^
4
```

#### Second approach to use *pairwise*

```py
from itertools import pairwise

def count_adj(L):
    return sum(a == b for a, b in pairwise(L))   # more efficient
```

Comment: Use `itertools.islice(nums, 1, None)` instead of `nums[1:]` to avoid making a copy of (most of) `nums`.

Comment: Agreed.  Just try to offer a simpler approach to new learner here.

Comment: Or do this one line: >>> sum(a == b for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:]))

Comment: That's a great way to work around the loop issue. because I want to make sure that the last element is being looked at. I will try it with the more complicated code I am working on. Thanks

Comment: You can also try the *itertools* *pairwise*,  eg. ```sum(a== b for a, b in (pairwise(L)))```  that's more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(n):
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(n) - 1):  # changed here
        if n[i] == n[i+1]:
            counter += 1
    print(counter, n[i])
```

Note that the last element of the list *isn't* ignored - it's compared with the second-to-last lement of the list.

---

`range(len(n))` will generate  `0, 1, ..., len(n) - 1`. Note that `len(n) - 1` is the last index in the list, since lists are zero-indexed.

Similarly, `range(len(n) - 1)` will generate `0, 1, ..., len(n) - 2`.

The last iteration of the loop will have `i = len(n) - 2`. Note that `n[i+1]` will access the last element of the list, because `len(n) - 2 + 1 == len(n) - 1`.

Comment: but the last element is not being printed now and that's the problem. I am using print here for simplification but I plan to do a more complicated thing to elements other than printing.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
if n[i] == n[i+1]:
```

to

```
if (n[i] == n[i+1])& (i!=n):
```

or

```
if (n[i] == n[i+1]) and (i!=n):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(n):
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(n)):
           if i == j: counter += 1
              
    return counter
```

or
if the array can be combined to a list, you could use this

```
   def counter(n):
       count = 0
       for num, num1 in zip(n, n[1:]):
          if num == num1:
            count += 1
          return count
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Thanks!